# Error when trying to use df.merge: "You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pubchem

I'm currently trying to write a program that takes a chemical compound's identifier (something called the CID number) and then gives back the compound's properties by using the pubchempy documentation.

However, I keep getting an error when I try to merge the data values that I get from pubchempy to the initial database.

This is the code I've written for now:

```
import pandas as pd
import pubchempy
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("Data.tsv.txt", sep="\t")

from pubchempy import get_properties

df['CID'] = df['CID'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.replace('.0',''))
df['CID'] = df['CID'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.replace('0',''))

df = df.drop(df[df.CID=='nan'].index)

df = df.drop(labels='reference', axis=1)
df = df.drop(labels='group', axis=1)
df = df.drop(labels='comments', axis=1)
df = df.drop(labels='compound_name', axis=1)

props = ['HBondDonorCount', 'RotatableBondCount', 'MolecularWeight', 'HBondAcceptorCount']
df2 = pd.DataFrame(get_properties(identifier=df.CID.to_list(), properties=props))

df = df.merge(df2)

print(df)
```

However, I get an error message that says,

```
ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

---

Few lines of text file (datafile):

```
NO. compound_name   IUPAC_name  SMILES  CID     Inchi   threshold   reference   group   comments
1   sulphasalazine  2-hydroxy-5-[[4-(pyridin-2-ylsulfamoyl)phenyl]diazenyl]benzoic acid O=C(O)c1cc(N=Nc2ccc(S(=O)(=O)Nc3ccccn3)cc2)ccc1O    5339    InChI=1S/C18H14N4O5S/c23-16-9-6-13(11-15(16)18(24)25)21-20-12-4-7-14(8-5-12)28(26,27)22-17-3-1-2-10-19-17/h1-11,23H,(H,19,22)(H,24,25)      R2|R2|R25|R46|  A   
2   moxalactam  7-[[2-carboxy-2-(4-hydroxyphenyl)acetyl]amino]-7-methoxy-3-[(1-methyltetrazol-5-yl)sulfanylmethyl]-8-oxo-5-oxa-1-azabicyclo[4.2.0]oct-2-ene-2-carboxylic acid   COC1(NC(=O)C(C(=O)O)c2ccc(O)cc2)C(=O)N2C(C(=O)O)=C(CSc3nnnn3C)COC21 3889    InChI=1S/C20H20N6O9S/c1-25-19(22-23-24-25)36-8-10-7-35-18-20(34-2,17(33)26(18)13(10)16(31)32)21-14(28)12(15(29)30)9-3-5-11(27)6-4-9/h3-6,12,18,27H,7-8H2,1-2H3,(H,21,28)(H,29,30)(H,31,32)      R25|    A   
3   clioquinol  5-chloro-7-iodoquinolin-8-ol    Oc1c(I)cc(Cl)c2cccnc12  2788    InChI=1S/C9H5ClINO/c10-6-4-7(11)9(13)8-5(6)2-1-3-12-8/h1-4,13H      R18|R26|R27|    A
```

---

Few lines of **df2** output:

```
        CID MolecularWeight  HBondDonorCount  HBondAcceptorCount  RotatableBondCount
0      5339           398.4                3                   9                   6
1      3889           520.5                4                  13                   9
2      2788          305.50                1                   2                   0
3   1422517           440.5                0                   8                   4
4  18595497           461.5                5                  10                   3
```

Comment: What are the indexes of the two dataframes?
By Default it merges on indexes of the two DF. you can specify the columns to merge on. Refer https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html

Comment: Beside the point, but why do you do multiple `df.drop(labels=..., axis=1)`? You could do them all together, plus you could use *columns* instead: `df = df.drop(columns=['reference', 'group', 'comments', 'compound_name'])`

Comment: What is the desired output, for the few lines of input shown? (If that does not make sense, please try to construct a small dataset that can be used to test the code.) How do you intend for the merge to work?

Comment: The formatting of your TSV has gotten messed up since Stack Overflow converts tabs to spaces. It'd be better to post a [reproducible pandas example](/q/20109391/4518341). (See also [mre].)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to merge two dataframes on `CID` column. `CID` column type of `df2` is `int`, you need change it to object to match the type of `CID` in `df`

```py
df = df.merge(df2.astype({'CID': str}), on='CID')
```